# Unable to get Ethernet on three Macbooks

Tags: ethernet

We have three Macbook Pros in use in our house and I am unable to get wired ethernet connection from the router to any of them. I have two ethernet cables and have tried with both.
Two of our Macbooks (both High Sierra) have a dedicated ethernet port, but when connecting directly from those to the router, Ethernet is 'not connected' in Network prefs, and the 'Cable unplugged - Either the cable for Ethernet is not plugged in or the device at the other end is not responding' message is showing. I've tried deleting the 'Ethernet' in the LH pane and then reconnecting, re-adding 'Ethernet'; I've tried hitting 'Advanced' and 'Renew DHCP lease'; I've tried restarting the Macs, router and modem - nothing works.

The third Macbook is a 2019 model (running Catalina) which only has four ports,all Thunderbolt so I'm using a Lention USB-C hub with 3 USB-2 ports plus an ethernet port to attach the ethernet cable (it shows up in my USB device tree in Mac System Info). In Network prefs 'Ethernet' is not even listed as a possibility; the alternatives (apart from Wi-Fi, which is working) are 'Bluetooth PAN', 'USB 10/100 LAN' and 'Thunderbolt Bridge' (4 of those). The USB 10/100 LAN, which I assume is the one I need, has the same message as above 'Cable not connected' (etc).

I need ethernet to work as I'm doing a lot of work via Zoom (who isn't!) and our wi-fi drops quite often.
I'm completely stuck and mystified by this. I've also tried installing some 3rd-party drivers; tried changing the 'Location ' in Network prefs; tried a suggestion about Incompatible Kernel Extension Configuration file, followed the steps, no change.

One more question - could this be a cable issue? Do I need something more than a standard ADSL RJ11 to RJ11 cable (which is what I have two of)? I note that the options in Network include USB 10/100 Lan, but not 10/100/1000 LAN? Is this the issue?
Any suggestions? All help gratefully received.

Comment: Ethernet runs on RJ45 not RJ11. Plugging RJ11 to ethernet could damage it.

Comment: The 10/100/100 indicates the maximum mbit/s so, if you have 10/100 that means your maximum speed will be 100mbit/s.

Comment: So what happens if you connect 2 MacBooks directly with the Ethernet cable? [This should work](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/mac-help/mchlp1413/mac) if the cable(s) are okay.